# How to rotate a node around a point outside of the object (i.e don't rotate around the center point of the object)

Tags: swift, xcode, rotation, skspritenode

**What I have Right now**, my game loads up on the simulator on Xcode as it should, but when I tap the screen, "basic Top" doesn't rotate. Basic top is one of four triangles that makes up a square.

**What I want** In order to make that square rotate I have to get all four triangles to rotate. Right now, basic top doesn't rotate even when I click on the screen. Once I get basic top to rotate, I can replicate the code for the other triangles in order to make a square that rotates. I need these four triangles all to rotate around a certain point.

**Code**

```
class GameScene: SKScene { 
var brickSwitch: SKSpriteNode!
var basicTop = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Top Side");
var basicBottom: SKSpriteNode!
var basicLeft: SKSpriteNode!
var basicRight: SKSpriteNode!   
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
layoutScene()     
}

func turnBasicTop() {
  basicTop.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
  basicTop.run(SKAction.rotate(byAngle: .pi/2, duration: 0.25))
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    turnBasicTop()
}

func spawnBasicTop() {
let basicTop = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "basic top")
basicTop.size = CGSize(width: 400, height: 400)
basicTop.position = CGPoint(x: 230, y: 200)
basicTop.zPosition = 1

basicTop.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: basicTop.size)
basicTop.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.basicTopCategory
basicTop.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
basicTop.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = true

addChild(basicTop)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `basicTop` defined in `spawnBasicTop()` refers to the local variable defined within the method as a local variable with the same name as another variable with a greater scope takes precedence in reference. Hence, when you attempt to run an animation on `basicTop` in the `turnBasicTop()` method, the action is run on a completely separate `SKSpriteNode` instance. I suppose you aren't seeing anything happen because either the node referenced by the scene's `basicTop` property is out of the view; has its `isHidden` property as true; or cannot be assigned to the image `"Top Side"` since it doesn't exist and therefore has zero size. Adding

```
self.basicTop = basicTop
```

to the `spawnBasicTop()` method will do the trick, although I recommend you learn more about Swift and how variables are declared, captured, etc.